# My code continues to say it's wrong in the autograder due to my inputs being counted as an output

Tags: python, list, output

I cannot get the autograder to stop looking at the inputs as an output. Everything I attempt to do anything it won't even act like it considers what i did

Tried adding a new line command, tried adjusting where the inputs went. Nothing worked

```
first_number = int(input("What is the first of the two numbers you would like to check?: "))
last_number = int(input("what is the second of the two numbers you would like to check?: "))

def number_is_a_prime_number(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, round(number/2) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes_to_be_listed(first, last):
    prime_list = []
    for number in range(first, last + 1):
        if number_is_a_prime_number(number):
            prime_list.append(number)
    print(f"The list of prime numbers between {first} and {last}:\n") 
    for prime in prime_list:
        print(prime)

primes_to_be_listed(first_number,last_number)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. If you're experiencing a bug with the autograder, what do you want us to do about it? Have you tried contacting the provider instead? On the other hand, if there's a a problem with your code or if you're not sure, then be detailed: what inputs do you give (or what inputs does the autograder give), and what's the outcome exactly? See [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "autograder".  Please show us exactly how you run this code, and the exact results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that it prints variable "first_number" and "second_number" in the output, even if its not prime? If so, I run this with the first number as 0 and second number as 100 in my software.

Output:

What is the first of the two numbers you would like to check?: 0
what is the second of the two numbers you would like to check?: 100
The list of prime numbers between 0 and 100:

2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97

All in all, I think its your software or compiler, what are you using?
Note: I also did this in a online compiler and came to same conclusion, if I'm wrong, sorry.